# How can I reindex a series created through the collapsing of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the code below:

```
sfix = sub['fix']  # a pandas.Panel
(sfix.minor_xs('tstop') - sfix.minor_xs('tstart'))  # slicey slicey!
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 804 entries, 0 to 803
Data columns (total 8 columns):
0    573  non-null values
1    675  non-null values
2    804  non-null values
3    715  non-null values
4    578  non-null values
5    568  non-null values
6    664  non-null values
7    599  non-null values
dtypes: float64(8)
```

This output corresponds to the difference between the `tstop` and `tstart` columns for each of the 8 DataFrames contained in the Panel object.

These columns all contain an identical kind of data, and I'd like to stack them into a single series, ergo:

```
s = pd.concat([df[i] for i in df])
```

This is a good start, but now all my indexes are duplicated 8 times:

```
>>> s.ix[0]

0     98
0    184
0    178
0    188
0    176
0    234
0    128
0     82
dtype: float64
```

From here, I can't quite figure out how to reindex my series such that the indexes go from 0 to `len(s)`.  I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
s.reindex(copy=True)
s.reindex(index=xrange(len(s)), copy=True)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work too

```
s = pd.concat([df[i] for i in df], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This appears to do exactly what I wanted.  Just to be doubly sure:  does this preserve the order of data?

Comment: I believe it does (this works) - 
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({0:[0]}), pd.DataFrame({0:[1]})], ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
>>> s
0     98
0    184
0    178
0    188
0    176
0    234
0    128
0     82
Dtype: float64
>>> s.reset_index(drop=True)
0     98
1    184
2    178
3    188
4    176
5    234
6    128
7     82
Dtype: float64
```